# Whow to use callback_query_handler in Python 3.10

Tags: linux

In my code

```
@telebot.TeleBot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True )
def answer(callback):
```

I get error:

```
TypeError: TeleBot.callback_query_handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I'm using these versions:

- Python 3.10
- telebot 0.0.5

What can I do to fix this problem?

I've write my first bot for telegram and I need buttons
I saw on youtube this code working @client.callback_query_handlers(func=lambda call: True), but this code get me another error: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

And I can't understand whow can I use callback_query_handlers in Python 3.10 and up.